# PHP Show Error Logs on Linux

Tags: php, linux, error-log

I'm using PHP as scripting language to create web application. My question is how could I see error logs on linux? i forgot the comman, It's something like `tail -f blabla`

Comment: Depends on the location of the apache error log file. For example: `tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log`

Comment: `tail -n50 /var/log/apache2/error.log` on debian

Comment: try:

<code>  watch tail path/to/error/log  </code>

so you could see the changes in the file every 2 seconds! :)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your distribution and how Apache was installed (I assume you're using Apache). You should find the relevant log in /var/log or /var/log/httpd. Once you find the right log file, you could watch it with `tail -f <file>`.

You can also configure PHP to display errors in the script output via the display_errors switch in php.ini. Do `php -i | grep php.ini` to figure out where your relevant php.ini is (typically /etc/php.ini).